# Displaying a list of objects with Views - Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views, content-type

I'll briefly explain what I'm trying to do:

I need to sort a set of **content-types** within a paginated page. Also I need to add filtering to the page, for example each content-type should have a set of **tags** and the filter **needs to filter through these tags**.

This is a basic mockup of what this page consists of:
[image]

---

**I'm finding it quite hard figuring out the best way to do it, and if this can be done.**

Help would be very much appreciated!!

Comment: What are the 'objects'? Nodes? Or actual names of content types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by tags you mean taxonomy, you just add a taxonomy filter in the view and expose it. What you need to achieve is simple and generic. So a correct answer is ti suggest you go through Views Documentation http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/